# Possible to update nodes key in a red-black tree, without removing and inserting?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, insert-update, red-black-tree

Typically changes to a key in a red-black tree need to be performed by removing, then re-inserting the node.

Is it possible to performs key updates to a node in a red black tree that is more efficient than delete+insert?

Comment: What's a key update? Removing a key-value pair, re-inserting the value under a new key?

Comment: @delnan while re-inserting is typically used - there would be times updating in-place is faster. It's an interesting question! - Did anyone try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement update with [search if required +] delete + insert

1 - delete the key *O(log n)*
2 - insert a new node with the new key *O(log n)*
Even if you search for a key first, it's *O(log n)*.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) page for more details on RBT.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete, an algorithm could at least check if the order is unchanged with relation to other nodes. And while I don't _know_ if its possible, it seems plausible that certain operations could be performed without a full delete+insert.